How to reconcile literate and \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile?
I am currently trying to write the source code in the lstlistings environment to a file and read it using luaLatex. However, I found that the characters specified for literate in the language styling (e.g. periods and commas) are not saved in the file. Any good ideas to reconcile these two? Also, is there another way to save within lstlistings?

\begin{luacode*}
function readtxt(filename, suffix)
  local body = ""
  local suffix = suffix or ""
  local firstline = true
  for line in io.lines(filename) do
    if not firstline then
      body = body .. "ABC<br>XYZ"
    else
      firstline = false
    end
    body = body .. line
  end
  return body
end
\end{luacode*}

\makeatletter
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
\lstnewenvironment{zennlisting}[1][]{%
  \lstset{language=#1}%
  \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.txt}%
}{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile%
  \def\test{\jobname.txt}%
\vspace*{-1em}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\mediabutton[%
  jsaction={
    var fld = this.addField("ToCopy", "text", \thepage-1, this.getPageBox({nPage: \thepage-1}));
    fld.textSize = 0.1;
    fld.fillColor = color.transparent;
    fld.multiline = true;
    fld.value = "\directlua{tex.sprint(readtxt('\test'))}".replace(/ABC<br>XYZ/g, String.fromCharCode(10));
    fld.setFocus();
    app.setTimeOut("app.execMenuItem('SelectAll');", 10);
    app.setTimeOut("app.execMenuItem('Copy');", 15);
    app.setTimeOut("this.removeField('ToCopy');", 20);
  }]{
    \includegraphics[width=5mm]{copy_icon.png}
  }
}

\makeatother


Welcome! Can you please add a short example of code that shows the issue?

@egreg Of course! But I'm trying to do something a little special and .... The situation may be hard to grasp. After loading and saving the source code, I load it with luaLaTeX and mount it in mediabutton. This way I can make a button that copies the source code to the clipboard with a click... I think.
